# What is the effect of semicolon on the running time complexity of the algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

```
for(i = n / 2; i <= n; i++)
{
    for(j = 1; j <= i; j = 2 * j)
    {
        for(k = 1; k <= n; k = k * 2)
        {
            printf("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Is the answer O(n^2 log n(log n))?

What is the effect of making one for loop ineffective by inserting semicolon after it to make it a null statement ,so now will it contribute for measuring the complexity of the algorithm ?

```
for(i = n / 2; i <= n; i++)
{
    for(j = 1; j <= i; j = 2 * j);// performs no action 

    for(k = 1; k <= n; k = k * 2)
    {
        printf("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: adding a semicolon just does the inner loop once as opposed to log(i) times.

Answer (score 1):

It does perform an action

```
for(j<=1; j<=i ; j=2*j);// performs no action
```

is set to **j=2^x where j>i**.